# Implementing trial app in C#

Tags: c#, trialware

#### Duplicate

> [Time bomb needed in asp.net application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564221/time-bomb-needed-in-asp-net-application)

---

I've done developing my app in C#. I need some info of how I can implement 'trial' functionality for my app (I want to let the user use the app for 30 day for example)

Comment: It's not quite a duplicate, because the time-bomb question was relating specifically to coding, whereas Cornel seems open to third party tools. Also, time-bomb included constraints such as 'client has access to code'.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at these tools:

- [.NET Licensing Pro](http://www.licensingdotnet.com/)
- [SerialShield SDK](http://www.ionworx.com/serialshield.html)
- [PC Guard](http://www.sofpro.com/)
- [Maxtocode](http://www.maxtocode.com/)
- [DeployLX Licensing](http://xheo.com/products/copy-protection)

Comment: k, but what's the best solution? I also need to restrict the user using some functionalities of my app if in trial mode

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of good answer in this question
[Time bomb needed in ASP.NET application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564221/time-bomb-needed-in-asp-net-application)

Answer (score 1):

There's also the solutions from Xheo, in particular [DeployLX](http://www.xheo.com/products/licensing/default.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

A specific commercial solution I've used is from [Aladdin](http://www.aladdin.com/hasp/default.aspx). They offer a USB dongle or a "software dongle" that allows you to pick and choose what features are enabled/disabled. The USB dongles even come with a battery-operated clock sealed in them so that gaming the system clock doesn't get around your protection.

Some people may say that any system like this can be broken. This is true. However, I've found Aladdin tools can be used to make cracking very difficult. Pair that with improving your protection on subsequent releases and what you get is a product that takes a lot of time and effort (cost) to break.

There's a related discussion on this SO question: [Software evaluation licensing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49662/software-evaluation-licensing).

Answer (score 0):

You can also check [LicenseSpot](http://www.licensespot.com) which gives you the ability to control the license via the online license manager with activation, revoking and trial extensions.